# Azure AD User login fails even after admin consent in multi tenant web app

Tags: permissions, multi-tenant, azure-active-directory

I am running into the following issue while allowing administrators to sign up a company.

1)I created a multi-tenant web application with Azure authentication
    and deployed to Azure.

2)Under the Windows Azure AD permission settings for this app, I checked
    the following permissions

```
 Application Permissions :  Read Directory Data
 Delegated Permissions : Sign in and read user profile
```

3)When I try to launch the application and sign in as a user  I am
    presented with a screen that says

> This application requires application permissions to another
>   application. Consent for application permissions can only be performed
>   by an administrator. Sign out and sign in as an administrator or
>   contact one of your organization's administrators.

4)I logged in as the admin and I am now presented with the admin consent screen. After accepting, I was able to browse through the website.
[admin consent screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvUk5.jpg)

5)When I logged back as the user, i am still presented with the same application permission error screen. As the admin has already consented, I would expect that the user can now sign in to the web app.

Please let me know if i need to set anything else.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a link and/or button into your app that allows to consent for their tenant by including `prompt=admin_consent` in your OAuth2/Open ID Connect authorization request.

The "Admin consent" portion of this document goes into more detail:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#admin-consent

Comment: So even though  the admin consent screen says that the permission will be granted to all users of the tenant, we will still need to add a separate btn which when clicked will explicitly grant admin_consent

Comment: The dialog pictured says that you're granting access to resources belonging to all users, because as an admin it will have access to potentially all user resources, not that all users will have access. I admit the language in the dialog is confusing. I'll see what I can do to report that internally.

Comment: Did this fix the issue @Jso?